# Property binding on the template with condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a generic component that represents a menu.
for some buttons I want to redirect to some other state, and for some buttons on the menu I want to perform an action inside the same page.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of section.items">
      <button mat-menu-item
                    [disabled]="item.disabled"
                    [routerLink]="item.link? item.link: undefined"
                    [queryParams]="{institution: institutionCode}"
                    (click)="!item.link ? onItemAction(item.action) : undefined">
                          {{item.label}}
            </button>
</ng-container>
```

The problem is that when I want to perform an action and and stay on the same page, the queryParams are deleted and set to only "institution".
Is there a better way to include [routerLink] and  [queryParams] attributes with a condition without just copying the button, one with these attributed and one without, each with *ngIf?
I just want that when I don't have link that there attributed will not appear and change mu url.

Comment: Is the above code working for you?

Comment: sure, I added he ng-container above.

Comment: instead of doing it in the HTML, you can write a `get` function in the ts that do this and get called in the HTML.  That way you can form the URL, including adding the queryparams

Comment: yes, I will do that. I just thought that maybe there is a way to do it in the template.

Comment: hint => `(click)="!item.link ? onItemAction(item.action) : router.navigate(['./to/path'])"`